# Why use filters in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm struggling to understand why I should be using `filter`s in Angular over vanilla functions…  Functionality seems basically the same; is there something going on behind the scenes, "readability" of the HTML, or something else?

```
{{val|number}}
```

looks pretty similar to:

```
{{number(val)}}
```

to me.  Presuming I've set `$scope.number=$filter('number')`, but for my custom filters it can be much more work to create an officially blessed filter vs. a function.

Comment: Not really. Filters can be chained, but so can functions if coded in that way. Main benefit in my opinion are the built-in filters.

Comment: once a filter is defined, it's usable from any view, and can be injected in any other angular component. A function must be defined on the scope to be available in the view, and it can't be injected unless it's a service.

Comment: Filters are the only type in angular that can be injected into a template without involving a controller or directive.

Comment: @JBNizet Should be an answer, unless this is a dupe.

Comment: So it's mostly a modularity/code reuse issue?  I was wondering about performance issues like `$stateful`, can those also be triggered? maybe I should look into the `$digest` cycle…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter is usable from any view, and can be injected into any other angular component.

A function must be defined on the scope associated to the view (or in a parent scope) to be available to that view, and it can't be injected unless it's a service.